# Using a variable to set properties of a control (The variable contains the name of the control) in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, variables, controls

For example, in visual basic

```
Dim VariableName As String
VariableName = "button1"
VariableName.Visible = true
```

Would set button1 to be visible.

Edit: I got it!

```
Me.Controls(variableName).Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well VariableName is a string, and strings don't have a a property called "visible".

You want to get the actual Button itself.  One way you could do that is something like (untested):

```
dim btn as Button
for each c in Controls
  if c.name = "button1" then
    btn = c
  end if
next
btn.visible = true
```

Edit: OP found a better solution, although this could work if you were looking for a textbox with a particular "text" property or something along those lines.